# "JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory" gradlew error on Fedora linux

Tags: java, android, linux

I installed Oracle JDK specially to work in Android studio, but it doesn't work for some reason:

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/java/jdk-10.0.2/
```

I already selected this java version in alternatives list. I also tried to use /java/latest, but the same error occurs. JAVA_HOME is set in ~/.bash_profile. I tried both setting it directly to the java location:

`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk-10.0.2/`

and by the code below:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")
```

None of these worked.

Comment: What version of Gradle are you using? Must be at 4.7 to support Java 10. See https://docs.gradle.org/4.7/release-notes.html: *Java enthusiasts will be happy to read that this release supports running Gradle builds with JDK 10*.

Comment: can you do echo $JAVA_HOME? Check if the path is to bin.

Comment: @Andreas well, I have 4.4, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it is wrong path.
 You didn't put "/" before bin it should be either

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java/ | sed "s:bin/java::")
```

or

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:/bin/java::")
```

> as per oracle documentation

Install the JDK software.

Go to http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp.

Select the appropriate JDK version and click Download.

The JDK software is installed on your computer, for example, at `/usr/jdk/jdk1.6.0_02`. You can change this location.

Set `JAVA_HOME`.

Korn and bash shells:

```
export JAVA_HOME=jdk-install-dir
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Bourne shell:

```
JAVA_HOME=jdk-install-dir
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH
C shell:

setenv JAVA_HOME jdk-install-dir
setenv PATH $JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Change the permissions to enable you to run the GlassFish ESB Installer.

```
chmod 755 JavaCAPS.bin
```